# Airmon-ng on Termux(Android)

Tags: android, termux, aircrack-ng

I rooted my Redmi Note 10S to trying to use aircrack-ng, but It don't worked, because my phone's wifi chip isn't compatible with monitor mode.
So I bought a wireless adapter and type-c to usb adapter, and it also didn't worked. The adapter's chip is a MediaTek 6360(It appeared on dmesg when i boot with adapter already connected)

It appears on "termux-usb -l" as "/dev/bus/usb/001/002", i gave permission with "termux-usb -r /dev/bus/usb/001/002", but it also didn't appear on airmon-ng.
idk what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late response but what worked for me was installing a custom kernel.

https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/building-nethunter/

I didn't have to use the rom only the custom kernel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).